# Drag & Drop to create Outlet not working XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

XCode 9.3

I am creating an `UIImageView` as well as three buttons.
I am able to create a `IBAction` via Draggin & Dropping the Buttons into `ViewController.swift`. However, when I try Draggin & Dropping the `UIImageView` into `ViewController.swift` no `outlet`is created...

[image: Screenshot]

Why is that?

Edit: Screenshot of Utilitypan(?)

[image: Screenshot of utility pane]

Comment: are you new in ios?

Comment: @JigarDarji Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- make sure you drag to the class assigned to the vc that contains the imageView in IB , **note** there is no IBAction associated with `UIImageView` you have to drag it as outlet and add a tap gesture to it with setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true` 
[image]

2- make sure automatic is selected (not manual)
[image]

Comment: How do I check the class assigned to the vc that contains the imageView? It works with the buttons. Doesnt that mean the class is correctly assigned?

Comment: check the custom class in the top right of the top photo in answer , Do you want to create an action or outlet ??

Comment: I want to create an outlet. Whats supposed to stand in there? It says `UiImageView` in greyed out letters. When I type `ViewController` it doesn't accept it.

Comment: this as an example , you should type the name of the class that already contains the buttons outlets

Comment: The buttons are conencted via drag & drop in `ViewController.swift`. The classname there is `class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {...`

Comment: open utilities pane as in top photo select the yellow icon , then make a focus on right part , then control drag from the imageView